# length of Cardioid

Tags: integration

I need some help solving this peustion:

calculate the length of the cardiod:

$$({x^2+y^2-ax})^2=a^2(x^2+y^2)$$  $$a\gt 0$$

I should use  some integral to do this.

Comment: Are you familiar with polar coordinates?

Comment: Yes but I don't know which should I choose.

Comment: You should definitely choose polar coordinates for this problem. Solving it in Cartesian coordinates would just be masochistic.

Comment: @DavidH. Not so much masochistic ! I tried and it works ! Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Well, that's what I get for just making an assumption without bothering to check it. =p My thought was that figuring out how to break up the integrals to account for multivaluedness of $y$ in $x$ might create too much extra work. What issues did you encounter?

Answer (score 0):

Choose the natural transformation $$x = r \cos \theta, \quad y = r \sin \theta, \quad x^2 + y^2 = r^2.$$  Express the radius $r$ as a function of the angle $\theta$.  Then compute the arc length using the integral $$\int_{\theta = 0}^{2\pi} \sqrt{ r^2 + \Bigl(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\Bigr)^2 } \, d\theta.$$  Be careful when you perform the integration:  use the symmetry of the integrand over the interval of integration.